# Mongoose updateMany dynamically

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregate-functions

I have a collection which looks like this (fields removed for brevity):

```json
[
    { "id": "A", "name": "AA" ,"arrayField": [1, 2, 3] },
    { "id": "B", "name": "BB" ,"arrayField": [4, 5, 6] },
    { "id": "C", "name": "CC" ,"arrayField": [7, 8] }
]
```

*Consider each object as a document.*

---

Now in my application, after some business logic, I have an array of POJOs which look like this:

```json
[
    { "id": "A", "name": "AB", "arrayField": [1, 2, 3] },
    { "id": "B", "name": "VB", "arrayField": [4, 5, 6] },
    { "id": "C", "name": "DE", "arrayField": [7, 8] }
    { "id": "D", "name": "GG", "arrayField": [10, 11] }
]
```

**Note that these objects don't have the other fields required by the document.**

#### How can I update the MongoDB collection to reflect the same as in the array of objects?

- I would like to update **only** the `arrayField` and the `name` fields of documents with `id` **A**, B** and **C** to reflect the array of objects.
- There is also a new document with `id` **D** which have to be inserted in the collection (the other fields will be taken care of as they have default values in the schema).

### Things I've tried/thought of

*Note: `arr` is the array of objects being talked about.*

1. `updateMany` with `upsert`:

   ```js
   Model.updateMany({ id: { $in: arr.map(({ id }) => id) } }, arr, { upsert: true });
   ```
2. Mapping over the array of objects and updating with upsert:

   ```js
   await Promise.all(
       arr.map(({ id, arrayField, name }) => {
           return Model.updateOne({ id }, { $set: { arrayField, name } }, { upsert: true });
       })
   );
   ```

Is there any way to do this using transactions/aggregations/etc.?

Comment: Transactions are used to group multiple queries in a given session and allow you to roll back if something goes wrong in any of them. Aggregations give you the chance to shape and filter data during queries. I don't think either will be helpful to you here. 

What are your solutions not doing for you that you need them to do?

Comment: @NathanWiles Sorry, I wasn't aware what exactly transactions were. Talking about aggregations, I've seen that you can associate a "variable" in a stage and use that to update/find. Coming to the solutions, the first one doesn't work. The database remains unchanged. Also, won't it replace the whole document instead of just the fields I want to change? Second solution does the job! But won't it take N number of trips to the database where N is the length of `arr`?

Comment: @Abhijit I think Nathan made a reasonable note. For your second solution, if your only concern is the numbers of trips to database, [bulk operation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk/#ordered-and-unordered-bulk-operations) could be what you are looking for.

Comment: @ray Bulk operations look like the way to go. Will try that! Thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @ray suggested in the comments, I was looking for [bulk operations](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/js-bulk/). I did something along the lines of:

```js
const bulk = Model.initializeUnorderdBulkOp();
arr.forEach(({ id, arrayField, name }) => {
    bulk.find({ id }).upsert().updateOne({ $set: { arrayField, name } });
});
bulk.execute();
```